# Getting Picture from Twitter Picture Service

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Given the twitter picture url (uploaded from twitter), I am trying to get what picture it is.

Example: http://pic.twitter.com/mKzkUPo0  , I would need the picture source of this.

Is there an easy way to get this?  I know of include_entities, but I am trying to do it, without using that function onthe whole search call.

I thought about using get_info on the tweet , with include_entities, but it's an extra call.

Anyway to do this with API? or PHP . I know it's not documented, so maybe a PHP, CURL would work.

Thanks!